# Can we create shapes in streamlit [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, user-experience, streamlit

I need to add shapes in streamlit like square, triangle ,circle is it possible in any way like maybe with the use of html, css or some direct vote,

Comment: where do you want to add it? if to plot then you should check documentation for plots. If in  html then you can use `<svg>` to put some shape. And for square or circle you can even use `<div>` with CSS `border-radius`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use html to draw shapes on streamlit canvas but streamlit has its limitation, use `st.markdown(your_html_design_as_string, unsafe_allow_html=True)` to draw the shapes.

You can make those shapes dynamic by taking some user input for your design.

Follow [this](https://blog.jcharistech.com/2020/05/09/simple-css-shape-generator-app-with-streamlit-color-picker/) blog for more.